# Observes children controllers property

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'd like to access from the parentController to my childrenControllers attributes, but I don't know how to access them.
Basically, I need to observe an attribute inside all my children (undefined number of children) to count the number of element with the attribute `isChecked` to `true`

I tried to use the property `this.controllers` but this stays empty.

Do you have any idea how to do that?
I'm using Ember AppKit.

Parent controller:

In my template (`table.hbs`) :

```
{{#each item in items}}
    {{render 'table-item' item}} 
{{/each}}
```

In my controller (`table.js`)

```
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    countCheckboxes: function () {
        //Will count the number of attribute "isChecked" to true
    }.observes('/* children controllers attribute "isChecked" */');
});
```

Children controllers:

In my template (`table-item.hbs`)

```
{{input type="checkbox" checked=isChecked}}
```

In my controller (`table-item.js`)

```
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
   isChecked: false
});
```

Comment: Why access the controller? directly go to the items. But for that dont override isChecked on the ObjectController and leve it on the content. Build a computerd property depending `items.@each.isChecked` and then just use `this.get('items').filterBy('isChecked')`

Comment: The item doesn't have the property isChecked and will never have this property, I can't add it into my model. That's why I need it into my controller

Comment: why cant u add to the model? u dont have to declare the property on the model, just bind it to the model and it will work!

Answer (score 1):

this might help you

```
var YourParentController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions: {
   countCheckboxes: function(isChecked){
     //do something
   }
  }
});
export default YourParentController

export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
   needs: ['yourParentController'],
   isChecked: false,
   checkedChanged: function(){
     var parentController = this.get('controllers.yourParentController');
     parentController.send('countCheckboxes', this.get('isChecked'));
   }.observes('isChecked')

});
```

Comment: That's an interesting idea. Unfortunately I also need to change the value of all attributes `isChecked` from the parentController.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Saygun's answer, you can iterate the child controllers by iterating over your array controller's instance.  And if you want it to be reusable, you can just use `parentController` on the itemController instead of having to use the needs.

```
App.IndexController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController:'foo',
  actions: {
    isCheckedChanged: function(item){
      console.log(item);
    },
    selectAll: function(){
      this.forEach(function(item){ // this will be the item controller
        item.set('isChecked', true);
      });
    }
  }
});

App.FooController =Em.ObjectController.extend({
   isChecked: false,
   checkedChanged: function(){
     this.parentController.send('isCheckedChanged', this);
   }.observes('isChecked')
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xureholi/1/edit

Comment: I will be honest this answer is better then mine. I didn't know itemController property. Glad to learn something new. Thanks